# How to convert a list of Booleans to real values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, platypus

I am using Platypus in Python. The problem is, after the optimizations, when I need to see the variables it shows them in boolean format.

when I change the variables types to "Real", the variable results are shown as real numbers but when I choose the "Integer" type it shows them as booleans. 
So this is how one of the individuals look like:

```
[[True, False, True], [False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True], [False, True, True], [False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True], [True, False, True], [False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False], [False, True, True], [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False], [True, True, False], [False, False, False, True, True, False, False, True], [False, False, True], [False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False], [True, True, False], [False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, False], [False, False, False, True, False, True, False, True], [False, True, False], [False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True], [True, True, True], [False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True]]
```

Before entering the function, they are integers (I am doing this intentionally) but, after entering the function, the variables become a mixture of integers and real numbers.

Comment: Can you please show us the expected output? You already gived the input, if you share the output would be even better :)

Comment: Hi Esdras, Thanks for your reply. an expected result is some thing like this:  [7, 11.8, 5, 11.2, 7, 11.4, 7, 4.8, 5, 13.9, 4, 13.8, 3, 14.4, 6, 12.7, 5, 11.7, 3, 3.6] . This is just an example. The booleans list in my question is not a translation of this example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure about it and how this is working haha, may I see your code? In any case take a look at [this link](https://github.com/Project-Platypus/Platypus/blob/master/examples/example_permutation.py), I think will solve your problem... But case not take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/Project-Platypus/Platypus/tree/master/examples) maybe will help you :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for everyone encountering the same problem.

The list of booleans is a binary representation of the integer.
To convert the list of booleans (binaries) back to an integer you can do:

```
>>> bool_list = [False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
>>> int_value = int("".join([str(int(b)) for b in bool_list]), 2)
>>> print(int_value)
109
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the binary representation in solution.results did not work for me. Inexplicably, it returned an integer other than the one used in the optimization. Instead I use decode() to get the correct integer.

```
from platypus import *

def My_problem(x):
    print("Integer used in optimization: ", x[0])
    return [x[0]+x[1], x[0]**2]

var = Integer(0, 10)
problem = Problem(2, 2)
problem.types[:] = var
problem.function = My_problem

algorithm = NSGAII(problem, population_size = 5)
algorithm.run(5)

for solution in algorithm.result:
        # print(int("".join([str(int(b)) for b in solution.variables[0]]), 2)) # incorrect value 
        print(var.decode(solution.variables[0])) # correct value
```